# Laravel : Dynamic field validation

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

I have forms that are dynamically generated and I would like to apply a specific validation rule foreach different type of field available.

I can have this kind of forms dynamically created:

- 2 inputs and 1 textarea
- 1 checkbox and 2 selects
- 1 input and 2 checkboxes
- ...

This is handled like this

```
@foreach( $form->fields as $field )

    @if( $field->type == 'input' )

            {!! Form::label($field->id, $field->title) !!}
            {!! Form::text($field->id, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => $field->title]) !!}

    @elseif( $field->type == 'select' )    

            {!! Form::label($field->id, $field->title) !!}
            {!! Form::select($field->id, $field->options->pluck('description','id')->toArray(), null,  ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

    @elsif ...

    @endif

@endforeach
```

And I have this code

```
public function storeDynamic(Request $request)
{

    foreach ($request->except('_token') as $field_id => $value) 
    {
        $type = \App\Field::find( $field_id )->type;

        switch ( $type ) 
        {
            case 'input':
                //required
                break;

            case 'select':
                //required|max:255
                break;

             ...

        }
    }

    //Store in DB
    //Flash confirmation message
    //Redirect
}
```

Usually I use this kind of code for validation

```
$this->validate($request, [  
    'title' => 'required|max:145',
    'description' => 'max:255'
]);
```

I'm sure laravel has a magic way to do this but I can't find anything in [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation).

So is it possible to validate the field one by one through my loop?

### Edit

I've found the `validateAttribute($attribute, $rule)` function under `laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php`

I think that's what I need but I don't know how to import this to my controller. I tried many things like

`\Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateAttribute()` or
`\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::validateAttribute()`

But that is not working.

Comment: Maybe this can help you out https://ericlbarnes.com/2015/04/04/laravel-array-validation/

Comment: Why you need one by one instead you can [validate all array at once](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#validating-arrays).

Comment: @C2486 Because I don't know what is in the array. Otherwise I use this technique as explained in my post.

Comment: Share your all possible fields name and their validations ?